# Localhost connection refused in Docker development environment

Tags: php, curl, nginx, docker, docker-compose

I use Docker for my PHP development environment, and I set up my images with Docker Compose this way:

```
myapp:
    build: myapp/
    volumes:
        - ./myapp:/var/www/myapp

php:
    build: php-fpm/
    expose:
        - 9000:9000
    links:
        - elasticsearch
    volumes_from:
        - myapp
    extra_hosts:
        # Maybe the problem is related to this line
        - "myapp.localhost.com:127.0.0.1"

nginx:
    build: nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - myapp

elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:1.7
    ports:
        - 9200:9200
```

Nginx is configured (in its Docker file) with a virtual host named `myapp.localhost.com` (`server_name` parameter) and that points to the `/var/www/myapp` folder.

All this works fine.

But here is my problem: my web app is calling itself via the `myapp.localhost.com` URL with cURL (in the PHP code), which can be more easily reproduced by running this command:

```
docker-compose run php curl http://myapp.localhost.com
```

The cURL response is the following:

> cURL error 7: Failed to connect to myapp.localhost.com port 80: Connection refused

Do you have any idea on how I can call the app URL? Is there something I missed in my `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: From what I saw on the web, I should maybe add `- "nginx:myapp.localhost.com"` to the list of `links` in the `php` entry of `docker-compose.yml`. But this leads to a so called "Circular import" error when running docker-compose. Maybe https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/1676 will solve the problem in Docker Compose 1.5.

Anyway, I am open to any other solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Months later, I come back to post the (quite straightforward) answer to my question:

- Remove the `server_name` entry in the Nginx host configuration
- Remove the `extra_hosts` entry in `docker-compose.yml` file (not necessary, but it's useless)

Simply call the server with the Nginx container name as a host (`nginx` here):

```
 docker-compose exec php curl http://nginx
```

Comment: This answer does not solve the call to the virtual hosts, Which for me does not make sense to call the name of the container instead of calling the domain name or virtual hosts.